# Correct syntax fo CreateGovCloudAccount in the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-organizations, aws-govcloud

What's the correct way to create a govcloud account from the AWS cli?  For context, I  already have a govloud account and I'm trying to create a separate account I'll use as a subacount within govcloud.  Happy to do this from the console if that's easier too.

I can't find an example of how to actually call the api.I've tried:

```
create-gov-cloud-account --email email@email.com --account-name my_account

aws CreateGovCloudAccount --email email@email.com --acount-name my_account

aws create-gov-cloud-account --email email@email.com --acount-name my_account

CreateGovCloudAccount --email email@email.com --acount-name my_account
```

Any pointers or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would call it like:

```
aws organizations create-gov-cloud-account --email email@email.com --account-name my_account
```